# How to loop API calls through sets of two variables

Tags: arrays, bash, curl, nested-loops

I have a few hundred records I need to update via API. The update is to the same field, but each record won't necessarily be receiving the same value. This means I need two sets of variables, one for the record ID and another for the unique values to be entered. I was thinking I could accomplish this with cURL or bash but haven't been able to come up with a working script. Closest I got was the following where variable `$i` is for the four record ID's and variable `$j` is for the value (new date) each respective record will be updated with...

```
for i in "50446" "50513" "50526" "50546" ; do
for j in "2019-08-15 07:00:00" "2019-08-26 07:00:00" "2019-08-20 07:00:00" "2019-08-22 07:00:00" ; do

( curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-API-KEY:***************" -d "<invoice-header><payment-date>$j.000</payment-date></invoice-header>" -X PUT "https://dummy-environment.com/api/invoices/$i" ) &&continue

done
done
```

However, with the script above, the API looped through each record ID and updated all of them with the 4th (the last) date value specified in variable `$j`. It didn't pull each respective value from `$j`. Has anyone done something like this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Tested your code with `echo "$i --- $j"` in the inner loop and I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: You're doing every combination of `$i` and `$j`, is that what you really want? Or do you want the first `$i` to go with the first `$j`, second `$i` with second `$j`, and so on?

Comment: @Barmar My intent was for the first $i to go with the first $j, second $i to go with second $j, etc. But I found a way to execute this update via Rails console (the application is written in Ruby) so my issue is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: I clearly figured that out, since I posted an answer that shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an API call with every combination of `i` and `j`. If you just want corresponding elements of each list, put them in arrays, and then loop through the array indexes.

```
ids=("50446" "50513" "50526" "50546")
dates=("2019-08-15 07:00:00" "2019-08-26 07:00:00" "2019-08-20 07:00:00" "2019-08-22 07:00:00")
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#ids[@]}; idx++))
do
    i=${ids[idx]}
    j=${dates[idx]}
    curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-API-KEY:***************" -d "<invoice-header><payment-date>$j.000</payment-date></invoice-header>" -X PUT "https://dummy-environment.com/api/invoices/$i"
done
```

I'm not sure what you intended with `&& continue` in your loop. Since the loop continues automatically, there's no point in adding it as a conditional statement.